Checkbox screen reader announcement
I am testing application using screen reader NVDA. there is a checkbox, if I click on checkbox there will be dropdown will be display and it has 2 options
1.Accept
2. Reject
If I select Accept and tab on to next element and come back to current checkbox then if I click enter the there will be dropdown with options

Reject
clear


My question is: When screen reader focus on checkbox what should be announcement? And tap on to each option and when selecting accept then what should be the announcement?

First, we don't know what the current announcement is when the OP is using a screen reader. Is it already correct? Or is it wrong? We also don't see any code to verify if it's coded in a way that supports screen readers.
Here's what I'd check:

Are the checkboxes using a "checkbox" role?
Are ARIA labels being used?
Is "aria-checked" being set to true when the checkbox is checked?
Is "aria-checked" being set to false when the checkbox is not checked?

The screen reader is going to be looking at the ARIA settings to properly announce what's on the screen and the state of the checkboxes.
If using ARIA correctly, I'd expect something like the following depending on the state. Note, the order may be different, but the screen reader should indicate the element is a checkbox, the label associated with the checkbox, and the current state (checked/unchecked).

"checkbox, accept, unchecked"
"checkbox, reject, unchecked"
"checkbox, clear, unchecked"
"checkbox, accept, checked"
"checkbox, reject, checked"

